# Añadir/eliminar elementos a un combobox

Tags: jscript

Tengo un JScript que permite modificar ciertos metadatos de un archivo Mp3 desde un explorador de archivos. El control "Género" es una lista desplegable editable (combobox) con algunos géneros disponibles, y me gustaría que el usuario pudiera personalizar esta lista, es decir, que pudiera añadirle o eliminarle géneros.

Núcleo original del script:

```javascript
    var tab = scriptCmdData.func.sourcetab;
    var item = tab.selected_files(0);

    dlg.Control("archivo").value = item.name_stem;
    dlg.Control("titulo").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3title;
    dlg.Control("artista").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3artist;
    dlg.Control("album").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3album;
    dlg.Control("anio").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3year;
    dlg.Control("pista").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3track;
    dlg.Control("genero").label = item.metadata.audio.mp3genre;
    dlg.Control("comentario").value = item.metadata.audio.mp3comment;

    dlg.Show

    while (true) {
        msg = dlg.GetMsg();
        if (!msg.result) break;

        var sayGoodBye = false;
        var cmd = scriptCmdData.func.command;

        if (msg.event == "click") {
            switch (msg.control) {

                case "btn_guardar":
                    var cmdLine = 'SetAttr META' +
                        ' "title:' + dlg.Control('titulo').value + '"' +
                        ' "artist:' + dlg.Control('artista').value + '"' +
                        ' "album:' + dlg.Control('album').value + '"' +
                        ' "year:' + dlg.Control('anio').value + '"' +
                        ' "track:' + dlg.Control('pista').value + '"' +
                        ' "genre:' + dlg.Control('genero').value.name + '"' +
                        ' "comment:' + dlg.Control('comentario').value + '"' +
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (sayGoodBye) break;
    }
}
```

Si a este código le inserto delante las siguientes líneas, consigo modificar los géneros musicales en las configuraciones del script, pero cuando ejecuto el script, siempre se muestran los mismos géneros, los originales, y no los que aparecen en la configuración del script.

```javascript
initData.config_desc = DOpus.Create.Map();
configName = "genero";
initData.config_desc(configName) = "Personalizar géneros musicales"; 

var genero = DOpus.NewVector();

genero.push_back = "Balada";
genero.push_back = "Jazz";
genero.push_back = "Salsa";
genero.push_back = "Rock";
```

Answer (score 0):

Pedí ayuda en otro sitio y la respuesta dada fue insertar estas tres líneas:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Script.config[configName].count; i++) {
    dlg.Control("genero").AddItem(Script.config[configName][i]); // Add each item to drop-down list
}
```

Debajo de la línea:

```
dlg.Control("genero").label = item.metadata.audio.mp3genre;
```

Y realmente todo funciona perfecto!